# How do I view console.log from BrowserComponent in Codename One?

Tags: java, codenameone

How can I view javascript log output from a BrowserComponent for the purpose of debugging my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `setDebugMode(true)` on the browser component you can also invoke a logging call using the sample in the [javadocs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/javascript/package-summary.html).